# how can i remove the event listener of html in chrome extensions?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

im creating an extension for chrome and i have a question.
i want to know, how can i remove an event from an element?
this is my event handler:

```
const handler = function (e) {
  console.log("on");
};
```

i want my extension to add a `mousemove` event to `html` tag. and i did that.

```
document.querySelector("html").removeEventListener("mousemove", handler);
```

i want to do something that when user clicked on my extension icon, if the badge text is on, remove the event listener from the `html`; but i dont know how to remove the event listener from `html` tag! i tried but i couldnt.

```
chrome.scripting.executeScript({
  target: { tabId: tabs[0].id },
  function: myFuntion,
  args: ["remove"],
});
```

i tried `removeEventListener` but it didnt work. i defined my function in global scope and it didnt work and i got an error that your function is undefined. i even tried to store the function in chromes storage! and etc.
but how can i remove the event listener from html tag when developing an extension for chrome?
thanks for helping.

Comment: hello. thank you very much! it worked! if you like, post your comment as an answer and i'll mark your answer :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the code injected by executeScript runs, it creates a new function each time, so the previous function can't be removed because its internal pointer is different now.

You can persist the function via `window`:

```js
window.handler = window.handler || function (e) {
  console.log("on");
};
```

Then you can remove it later in another executeScript:

```js
document.querySelector("html").removeEventListener("mousemove", window.handler);
```